# Referencing macro variable in a CASE WHEN statement

Tags: sas, sas-macro, proc-sql, sas-studio

I have a proc sql statement which I am trying to expand to be as thorough as possible.

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE  &CURRENT_ID._SCR (drop = 
SDX
SPDS
CMPLV
CMPGD
Miss_Flag) AS
SELECT *,
CASE 
WHEN SDX = 1 AND CMPGD ne 0 THEN MAX(SPDS, CMPLV, CMPGD)*1.1 
WHEN SDX = 1 THEN 1

/*WHEN MISS_FLAG = 1 and &CURRENT_ID. = "MIDDLE"  THEN 30*/

WHEN MISS_FLAG = 1 THEN 100
ELSE CEIL(CMPGD)

END AS  &CURRENT_ID._SCR
FROM  &CURRENT_ID.
QUIT;
```

The statement runs fine until I attempt to include `WHEN MISS_FLAG = 1 and &CURRENT_ID. = "MIDDLE"  THEN 30`

I then get errors saying all 4 of the `&CURRENT_ID.` values are not found in the contributing table, not just the value of `"MIDDLE"`

I'm not entirely sure what the issue is as the values are present in the contributing table as they are correctly found on the other `&CURRENT_ID.` references. The table name and column names are generated correctly using the `&CURRENT_ID.` references. Can anyone see what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - Placing macro reference in `" "`

```
WHEN MISS_FLAG = 1 and "&CURRENT_ID." = "MIDDLE"  THEN 30
```

this correctly resolves.

Comment: Without quotes, SAS expects `&CURRENT_ID.` to be a SAS name, i.e. a column in your dataset.

Comment: Thank you @Therkel, I did realise after posting that was the case. When in the quotes what does SAS actually interpret "&CURRENT_ID." as? Does it just see it as the macro variable value so in this case just a string?

Comment: When using double quotes, `"`, the submission is done as normal, reacting to the special character `&` and looks for either a space or a period `.`. The macro processor then resolves the macro variable before processing. So SAS never sees `&CURRENT_ID.` but instead the value of the macro variable. If you use single quotes `'`, the macro processor ignores and SAS will see the unresolved string `&CURRENT_ID.`. See [How SAS Processes Statements with Macro Activity](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/mcrolref/p0znr2zp0ubdzjn10wmhw0y2ef1q.htm)